# Conditional auto increment value in SQL server "SELECT"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

**Data Available in Table1**

```
ID  Name1   Address
1   nm1     abc
1   nm2     def
1   nm3     ghi
0   nm4     jkl
0   nm5     mno
0   nm6     pqr
1   nm7     stu
1   nm8     vwx
1   nm9     yza
0   nm10    bcd
```

**Expected Output from Table1**

```
ID  Name1   Address Counter
1   nm1      abc      1
1   nm2      def      1
1   nm3      ghi      1
0   nm4      jkl      2
0   nm5      mno      2
0   nm6      pqr      2
1   nm7      stu      3
1   nm8      vwx      3
1   nm9      yza      3
0   nm10     bcd      4
```

Order must be sort using the key fields and need to generate the auto increment no in the expected output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are going to need to give us a column which can reliably generate the order we see in the current table.  Note that `Name1` won't work, because it mixes numbers as text, and the numbers won't sort properly.

Comment: What "key fields"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know how the rows are order. I suppose this is sample data and in your real scenario you can ordered the data in unique way. With your sample data I am using the following statement to order the rows:

```
CAST(REPLACE([Name], 'nm', '') AS INT)
```

There are different solutions of this (some depending on your SQL version, too). If you are using `SQL Server 2012+` you can use the `LAG` function to find if `ID` value is changed from the previous and current row and then to sum this changes using `OVER` clause:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] INT
   ,[Name] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[Address] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [Name], [Address])
VALUES (1, 'nm1', 'abc')
      ,(1, 'nm2', 'def')
      ,(1, 'nm3', 'ghi')
      ,(0, 'nm4', 'jkl')
      ,(0, 'nm5', 'mno')
      ,(0, 'nm6', 'pqr')
      ,(1, 'nm7', 'stu')
      ,(1, 'nm8', 'vwx')
      ,(1, 'nm9', 'yza')
      ,(0, 'nm10', 'bcd');

SELECT *
      ,SUM([change_made]) OVER (ORDER BY  CAST(REPLACE([Name], 'nm', '') AS INT))
FROM
(
    SELECT *
          ,IIF([ID] <> LAG([ID], 1, -1) OVER (ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE([Name], 'nm', '') AS INT)), 1, 0) AS [change_made]
    FROM @DataSource
) DS
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE([Name], 'nm', '') AS INT);
```

[image]